# VB.Net's For Next

Tags: vb.net

Is there a difference between these?

```
For i = 0 To Something.Length - 1
  'do something
Next

For i = 0 To Something.Length - 1
  'do something
Next i
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is only for readability:

> You can optionally specify counter in the Next statement. This improves the readability of your program, especially if you have nested For loops. You must specify the same variable as the one that appears in the corresponding For statement.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There is no difference. Even with nested loops there is no difference because nested for-loops cannot overlap.